# textract_python_table_parser.py command prompt lacking credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line, syntax, amazon-textract

I'm trying to put to work AWS's Textract export table suggestion in [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/examples-export-table-csv.html)
I'm a complete newbie in AWS's solutions and in command prompt so I'm trying to do exactly as they suggest. I'm running that in python so I'm using this piece of code:

```
import os
k=os.system("python textract_python_table_parser.py my_pdf_file_path.pdf")
print(k)
```

The code runs, I get an `Image loaded my_pdf_file_path.pdf` however at some point it bugs on credential matters:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/KlooksExplore/PDFWork/textract_python_table_parser.py", line 108, in <module>
    main(file_name)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/KlooksExplore/PDFWork/textract_python_table_parser.py", line 94, in main
    table_csv = get_table_csv_results(file_name)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/KlooksExplore/PDFWork/textract_python_table_parser.py", line 53, in get_table_csv_results
    response = client.analyze_document(Document={'Bytes': bytes_test}, FeatureTypes=['TABLES'])
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 622, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 641, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 116, in create_request
    operation_name=operation_model.name)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 160, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

I'm aware I didn't pass any credentials and that's natural to happen but where should I pass it and what would be the right syntax for that using python os? Amazon's example doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you run your code, for example:

- local computer - can use [aws configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-methods) CLI to set your credetnails
- EC2 instance - use [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)
- lambda function - use [lambda execution role](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=aws+lambda+execution+role&ia=web)